# How to insert Big Integer in prepared statement java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to insert a Big integer value using prepared statement, i have one string variable called xid (41527820021925053)

```
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setObject(1,XOBJ);
    preparedStatement.setObject(2,YOBJ);
    preparedStatement.setBigInteger(3, xid);
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, 23);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    preparedStatement.close();
```

I am new to this how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you actually talking about `java.math.BigInteger`?

Comment: *FYI:* According to [this comment by OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376198#comment68009412_40377394), this question is about the **PostgreSQL `bigint` data type**, not about the Java `BigInteger` type.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) doesn't have a `setBigInteger()` method.

Use one of these methods:

- [`setBigDecimal(3, new BigDecimal(xid))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBigDecimal-int-java.math.BigDecimal-)
- **[`setLong(3, Long.parseLong(xid))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong-int-long-) if value can fit within a `long`**
- [`setString(3, xid)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-) to let the JDBC driver convert the string for you

---

**UPDATE**

With the following [comment made by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376198#comment68009412_40377394), the second option above (now highlighted) is the correct option to use, since PostgreSQL `bigint` is the same a Java `long`.

> guys i am using postgres & it has bigint ["UniqueIdGenerator"()] data-type,which is a 17 digit big integer.

Comment: `setLong()` is the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an integer or long value in a String, then you should be able to just use `setString(idx, yourValue)`, `setObject(idx, yourValue)`, or `setObject(idx, yourValue, java.sql.Types.BIGINT)` the driver should convert this to the target type.

If you are talking about a `java.math.BigInteger`, then a JDBC 4.1 (or higher) compliant driver should allow you to set a `BigInteger` value to a `BIGINT`, `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` or `LONGVARCHAR` column using `setObject(idx, yourBigInteger)`, or `setObject(idx, yourBigInteger, targetType)` where `targetType` is for example `java.sql.Types.BIGINT` or `java.sql.Types.VARCHAR`.

However, be aware that not all drivers implement this support.

See [JDBC 4.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/index.html) section 3.1 *Overview of changes*, table B-4 *Mapping from Java Object Types to JDBC Types*, table B-5 *Conversions Performed by `setObject` and `setNull` Between Java Object Types and Target JDBC Types*. Or alternatively, [JDBC 4.2 specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html), but then only tables B-4 and B-5.

Comment: A SQL data type that can take 20+ digits for an integer value is likely defined a `NUMERIC(n, 0)` (or `DECIMAL` and/or without `0` argument or whatever the RDBMS dialect calls it), which is unlikely to be a JDBC type of `BIGINT`. As such, `setObject()` with a `BigInteger` value is fairly useless for anything other than text columns. If they at least had defined that `BigInteger` should map to `DECIMAL` / `NUMERIC`, the support for `BigInteger` would have been useful.

Comment: @Andreas That may be, but JDBC 4.1 **defines this mapping**, so drivers **must** support it. But it is a good point, I'll bring it up in the JDBC Expert Group.

Comment: Yeah, I think `BigInteger` should map to all the same JDBC types as `BigDecimal`. I mean, if `BigDecimal` can map to `TINYINT`, why can't `BigInteger`? Especially given that `BigInteger` is *logically* a `BigDecimal` restricted to a scale of 0.

Comment: guys i am using postgres & it has bigint ["UniqueIdGenerator"()] data-type,which is a 17 digit big integer.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I was also a bit surprised about that omission when I recently implemented support for this in Jaybird.

Comment: @Helper 17 digits fit in a long, so you don't even need to use `BigInteger` or a string.

Comment: That depends on our database structure, I can't do anything. i need to accomplish my task, thats it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel So you implemented all the mappings of course, right? ;-) The JDBC spec just lists the minimum required mapping support.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't, yet, but good point :). I reopened that improvement ticket.

Comment: @Helper You seem confused. The PostgreSQL data type [`bigint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) is *exactly* the same as a Java `long`, i.e. an 8-byte [two's-compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer value. So, if your question is about the PostgreSQL `bigint` type, and not about the Java `BigInteger` type, which is what it appears to be about, then please edit the question to clarify it, e.g. say the exact data type name and mention the RDBMS vendor / dialect.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct i have not tested for long thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setObject(1,XOBJ);
    preparedStatement.setObject(2,YOBJ);
    preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(3, BigDecimal.valueOf(Long.parseLong(xid))); //or you can try below
    preparedStatement.setBigDecimal(3, new BigDecimal(xid)); //both are correct
    preparedStatement.setInt(4, 23);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    preparedStatement.close();
```

Comment: If you use `parseLong()`, why not call `setLong()`? If you want to use `setBigDecimal()`, use `new BigDecimal(xid)`. As the answer is right now, it's wrong.

Comment: Both are only correct *if* the value of `xid` is limited to the range of values supported by `long`. Question doesn't specify if that is the case (example value is not an indicator of extreme value).

Comment: @helper mentioned that it was a 17 digit big number right and he has a string variable called xid.

Comment: You didn't know that when you wrote that "both are correct", so as far as you *knew*, they weren't not both correct. Now that you do know, they do both give the correct result for all input values, but the "correct" answer would be to use `setLong()`. If you always had in mind that value would fit in a `long`, then that should have been your answer from the beginning.