# Insert/update Hex value to DB2 Z/OS PreparedStatement

Tags: java, hex, prepared-statement, db2-zos

I need to insert in my database a Hex value with a PreparedStatement in Java.

I can do a select with Hex function for get my value:

```
String id = "02658947530232010038892587183C";
String request = "SELECT HEX(COLUMN) FROM TABLE WHERE HEX(COLUMN)=?";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
ResultSet rs = null;
try(PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement(request))
{
    insert.setString(1, id);
    rs = select.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    System.out.println(rs.getString("COLUMN"));
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    con.close();
}
```

My result is `02658947530232010038892587183C.` (this is an example).

But now i want insert a value in my table.
If i try:

```
String id = "02658947530232010038892587183C";
String request = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (X'?')";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(request))
{
    insert.setString(1, id);
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

Java does not recognize `?` parameter from "(X'?')` and i have an error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: invalid parameter.

If i try:

```
String id = "X'02658947530232010038892587183C'";
String request = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(request))
{
    insert.setString(1, id);
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

I also get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlDataException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-302, SQLSTATE=22001

Because it tries to insert `X'02658947530232010038892587183C'` as a string.

The only way I find to work it's this:

```
String id = "02658947530232010038892587183C";
String request = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (X'?')";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(request.replace("?", id))
{
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

However, this approach is not viable. Is there a way to do this properly ?

For reminder my database is a DB2 Z/OS and the function UNHEX doesn't exist.

More explanation:
In my request, `X'?'` is a function that is used to pack hexadecimal values.

The length `COLUMN` in my `TABLE` is 7. My length `id` is 14, I need to pack this id to insert him in my bdd. And when I want to read it in my java code.

I unpack the id with the function `HEX(id)`. But in DB2 Z/OS  the function `UNHEX` dosen't exist, we need to use `X'id'`, but like you can see `PreparedStatement` dosen't recognize this as a function.

When i pack this id `02658947530232010038892587183C` with the function `X''` the result in data base with `SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE` is `Áiåë�i  g` (the result you see is not the exact one I get because there are characters that the site cannot read).

And if i use the function `HEX()` in my select for unpack the id `SELECT HEX(COLUMN) FROM TABLE` the result will be I updated my question to show what I need to get when I pack my id. `02658947530232010038892587183C`.

Comment: Have you tried `X?`?

Comment: Not working either:
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601 ILLEGAL SYMBOL

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just convert it from Java?

```java
String id = "0038892587183C";
int idAsInt=Integer.parseInt(id, 16);
String request = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(request))
{
    insert.setInt(1, idAsInt);
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

This converts `id` from hexadecimal to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt` using a custom base `16` in order to parse it as a hexadecimal number.

Then, it uses `PreparedStatement#setInt` for setting the parameter without the `X''`.

If your hex number exceeds the signed 32bit limit of `int`, you would need to use `long` (signed 64bit) or `BigInteger`. Unfortunately, JDBC doesn't allow passing a `BigInteger` directly, so you would need to use a solution like [these mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376198/how-to-insert-big-integer-in-prepared-statement-java):

```java
String id = "0038892587183C";
BigInteger idAsBigInt=new BigInteger(id, 16);//parse it to a BigInteger
String request = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN) VALUES (?)";
Connection con = getConnectionDb2z();
try(PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(request))
{
    insert.setBigDecimal(1, new BigDecimal(idAsBigInt));//or possibly insert.setString(1, String.valueOf(idAsBigInt));
    insert.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I have an `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "02658947530232010038892587183C"`

And i dont think it's working because how can you be sure that if i pack my id with this in java, that when i unpack him with a `SELECT HEX(COLUMN) FROM TABLE` I will have the same id as beginning ?
When the function `X''` pack the id, it transform it with characters we cant read properly.

Example i pack the id "02658947530232010038892587183C" with my "ugly" method, this is the result is data base without `HEX()` ( `SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE`) : `"Áiåë�i  g"`.

Comment: I didn't know you were exceeding the integer limit. I have edited my question to work with bigger values.

Comment: It still doesn't work, it doesn't pack my id.
When I display what I try to insert with it gives me `7251696560555008041402765687593020` when I want a 16 character String.
And so I have an error `DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001 Value is too long`.
I updated my question to show what I need to get when I pack my id.